# Anyone know where I could find a free list of hedgefunds and their strategies...?

Tags: research

I am looking for a (free) list of hedgefunds with their strategies. I have found Barron's top 100 online but am having trouble finding a longer list. Any ideas of where to look?

Answer (score 1):

BarclayHedge. Various levels of detail.